# How to get accurate results from AvailablePhoneNumber LocalResource fetch when searching with "contains" parameter in Twilio?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I was refering to the below Twilio API link:
[Availablephonenumberlocal-resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/availablephonenumberlocal-resource)

In the example 3, "Find phone numbers by character pattern", it calls the API as:

**var local = LocalResource.Read(
contains: "STORM",
pathCountryCode: "US",
limit: 20
);**

In the above, it feeds "**contains**" parameter with value "**STORM**". However, the response for this example shows numbers with phone number code of "**Miami**" state.
Similarly, if I try to call the LocalResource api with "contains" parameter as "Chicago", I don't get any result from Twilio.
When I try to call LocalResource.Read without "contains" parameter, I see the phonenumbers from Chicago.
The same is the case with any other city in US or any other country. Twilio returns numbers only and only if I send "**contains**" parameter with "**STORM**" as value.
Could someone please explain me if I am doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it shows phone numbers from Miami is because **STORM** translates to **78676**, where **786** is the area code for Florida, and **76** further narrows down to a region which contains Miami, a major city in Florida.

The translation from STORM to 78676 is based on the numbers on a [dial pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad#/media/File:Telephone-keypad2.svg) that are associated with the letters that are also on them.
On the dial pad, 7 has letters pqr**s**, the S becomes 7, 8 has **t**uv, so T becomes 8, 6 has mn**o**, so O becomes 6, 7 has pq**r**s, so S becomes 7, and 6 has **m**no, so M becomes 6. There are some online tools that can convert this for you.

The `contains` parameter matches against the phone numbers themselves, not their location, so you can use number to match or characters, but these character translate to numbers as shown above.

To get phone numbers near Chicago you can use the `contains` parameter and find out the area code for that which seems to be `773` according to [this website](https://www.allareacodes.com/illinois_area_codes.htm), so you can use `+1773` to filter to those numbers.

You can also use other parameters to filter to specific locations such as `areaCode`, `nearLatLong`, `distance`, `inPostalCode`, `inRegion`, `inLata`, and `inLocality`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I want to understand that how does STORM translate to 78676? I apologise if the question is stupid but I am not from US so I am unaware of it.

Comment: @Ashish it's not a stupid question, in fact I didn't know this myself as it's not something commonly used outside of the USA AFAIK. [Phone dial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad#/media/File:Telephone-keypad2.svg) pads have 10 numbers on them, 9 of which have 3 or 4 letters on each of the numbers.
STORM translates to 78676 because that's the number that is on the dial with the corresponding letter. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Also could you please provide me a link or refer any website which has list of such words which translates to numbers like "STORM"?

Comment: Sure, I didn't link one because I personally don't like most of them as they have many ads and look unprofessional, but here you go: https://miniwebtool.com/word-to-phone-number-converter/

Comment: @Ashish if this solved your question, can you mark the question as solved? Thank you

Comment: Sure @Swimburger. I have one more question. Is there any API to get the area code based on the city name? For eg: If I need the area code of Chicago, is there any api where if I send Chicago as a parameter and get the area code of Chicago?

Comment: There's no API for looking up the area codes, but you [NANPA has a table of them here](https://www.nationalnanpa.com/enas/geoAreaCodeNumberReport.do). This only shows the area code and state/region, not cities.
I can't find phone numbers that are labeled as from Chicago, but using the parameters I mentioned, you can a number that's as close as possible.